# Amazon Lightsail LAMP app site can no longer be reached

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a LAMP app in Amazon Lightsail using Bitnami.  I was going to switch to a static IP.  For testing, I created a snapshot of the app.  The snapshot worked with a static IP.  When I tried to move the static IP over to the original instance, both instances gave me a `This site can’t be reached, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX took too long to respond`  I went back and tried to set up a 3rd instance off the snapshot and that will not work either.  I don't understand why even that one won't work.  I have tried in Chrome and Firefox with no luck.  I can reach the instances via the command lines which say that apache is running.

> Help me obi-stackoverflow-nobi.  You are my only hope!

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, could you please confirm the services are running in the new instances `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart` and that the ports are open in the firewall (port 80 and 443)? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response @JotaMartos.  I have tried that many times with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the way the site was built had the older IP saved in the database and the wordpress site was trying to go to the old IP instead of the newer one.  I changed the IP in the DB and restarted the apache server to a beautiful website.